# Stop div from side-scrolling in smaller-sized window. Overflow:hidden, wrapper div and fixed position don't work

Tags: html, css, overlap

I am fiddling with a website not created by me. On top of that I haven't coded in HTML/CSS in a LONG time. I'm having the issue of a side-menu (div's) horizontally overlapping over the div to it's right if the window is smaller than the body's width. I just want to prevent that from happening and continue with the vertical scrolling.

The problem is that there are quite a few divs inside this "menu"/side of the page div and some fancy stuff when the mouse hovers it. Is there a clean, easy way for a novice like me to just prevent the horizontal scroll when the browser window is smaller than the content? I've tried wrapping the whole body content and also setting all related divs to position:fixed, but it did not work. Any easy tips I could implement to solve this?

EDIT 2: I want to KEEP the scrollbar, I just don't want the div to move when I scroll.

EDIT: Posted the whole code, most of it is useless for the question, but since I don't know what could be useful, I posted it all. The issue is that "panel" is sliding above "entries" if the screen size is reduced.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
{block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}

<meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:text" content="#838282"/>
<meta name="color:link" content="#b8b8b8"/>
<meta name="color:link hover" content="#b8b8b8"/>
<meta name="color:title" content="#b8b8b8"/>
<meta name="color:sidelinks" content="#b8b8b8"/>
<meta name="color:sidelinks hover" content="#8b8b8"/>
<meta name="color:panel" content="#b8b8b8"/>

<meta name="image:background" content=""/>
<meta name="image:sidebar image" content=""/>
<meta name="image:sidebar background" content=""/>
<meta name="image:panel" content=""/>

<meta name="text:Custom Link One" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link One Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Two" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Two Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Three" content="" />
<meta name="text:Custom Link Three Title" content="" />


<meta name="color:scroll" content= />

<meta name="color:scrollbg" content= />

<meta name="if:Webkit Scrollbar" content="1" />

<style type="text/css">


a {color:;text-decoration:none;-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;transition: all 0.7s ease-out;}

.fufu {width:227px;-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;transition: all 0.7s ease-out;}

.fufu:hover {-webkit-transform: translate(1em,0);-moz-transform: translate(1em,0);-o-transform: translate(1em,0);}


html{
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}

body {
    background: {color:Background} url("{image:Background}") no-repeat;
    margin:auto;
    color:{color:text};
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:100%;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    -moz-outline-style:none;
    color:{color:link};
}


a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:{color:link};
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }

a:hover {
    color:{color:link hover};
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }

img {
    border:none;
}

blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid;
}
    
blockquote blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid;
}

h1 {
    font-size:15px;
}


#top_div{
    display: block;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    z-index:11;
    background-image: url("blah");
}
#top_menu{
    display: block;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:300px;
    float:left;
    z-index:10;
    background-image: url("");
}

#entries {
    padding:0px;
    width:530px;
    margin-left:470px;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight:normal;
    z-index=1;
  
}

    
#post {
    width:500px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    border-top: solid 11px #7e0925; 
    overflow:hidden;
    
   
}


#title {
    opacity:0;
    width:220px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: 'Vivaldi';
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:{color:title};
    line-height:100%;
    z-index:20;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
}


#panel:hover #title{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9a9a9a;
    opacity:1;
    width:270px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:-120px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: 'Vivaldi';
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:{color:title};
    z-index:0;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
  

#sidebar {
    width:216px;
    height:250px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:110%;
    font-family: 'Voltaire', sans-serif;
    z-index:1;
}

#panel{
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width:222px;
    height:762px;
    background:{color:panel} url("{image:panel}") no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#panel:hover{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width:222px;
    height:762px;
    z-index:10;
    background: {color:panel}:
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#panel:hover #sidebarimage{
    position:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:0px;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:3;
    border: solid 1px #fff; 
    outline: solid 2px #D8D8D8; 
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#panelbackground{
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:-178px;
    width:222px;
    height:762px;
    background:url("{image:panel}") no-repeat;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-delay: .1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .1s; 
    -webkit-transition-delay: .1s; 
    -o-transition-delay: .1s; 
}

#panel:hover #panelbackground{
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:-178px;
    width:222px;
    height:762px;
    background:url("{image:panel}") no-repeat;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#sidebarimage {
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:-38px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:3;
    border: solid 1px #fff; 
    outline: solid 0px #D8D8D8; 
   transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#sidebarimage img {
    width:200px; 
     transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.top{
    position:fixed;
    opacity:1;
    margin-top:270px;
    margin-left:190px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -5; 
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#navigation{
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    font-size:8px;
    margin-left:-70px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px;
    margin-top:-55px;
    width:40px;
    border:none;
}

#navigation:hover{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: -70px;
}

div.button{
    width: 85px;
}


div.button a{
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    background:none;
    z-index:2;
    width: 85px;
    height:25px;
    border-style:none;
    border-right:solid 10px;
    border-right-color: rgba(110,110,110,0.4);
    border-bottom:solid 1px {color:background};
    border-bottom-color:;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

div.button a:hover{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color: {color:sidelinks hover};
    position:relative;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    z-index:2;
    width: 60px;
    height:25px;
    border-style:none;
    border-right:solid 12px {color:background};
    border-bottom:solid 1px {color:background};
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
    
#description {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #2a2a2a;
    opacity:0;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    width:165px;
    padding:5px;
    background:{color:background};
    color: #D8D8D8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:217px;
    margin-left:-65px;
    line-height:120%;
    font-size:8px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 15px;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    
}
#panel:hover #description {
    opacity:1;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s
    transition-delay: .2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .2s; 
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s; 
    -o-transition-delay: .2s; 
}

#pagination {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
    color:{color:link};
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:oblique;
}


#quote{
    padding-top:5px;
    font-family:georgia;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:38px;
    margin-left:-3px;
}

.info{
    padding:2px;
    margin-left:515px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:9px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:left;
    opacity:0;
    background: none;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#post:hover .info {
    padding:2px;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:9px;
    width:80px;
    margin-left:512px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    text-align:left;
    opacity:1;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    z-index:3;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#post img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#post p{
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 11.5px;
}

ol.notes {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 25px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

ol.notes li.note {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

ol.notes li.note img.avatar {
    vertical-align: -4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

ol.notes li.note span.action {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol.notes li.note .answer_content {
    font-weight: normal;
}

ol.notes li.note blockquote {
    border-color: #eee;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 25px;
}

ol.notes li.note blockquote a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#asker {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
  
}

.bubble {align:right;background: #eee; margin:7px 0px 5px 66px;padding:10px;position: relative;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;}
.bubble p {margin:1px 0px;}
.bubble span {display:block;position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;font-size: 0;line-height: 1px;left:-10px;top:10px;border-top:7px solid transparent;border-bottom:7px solid transparent;border-right:10px solid #eee;}

.askborder {float: left;margin: 1px 4px 0 0;padding: 2px; background: #eee}

#audioplayer { 
width:30px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
margin-top:37px;
margin-bottom:45px;
margin-left:34px;
z-index:2;
opacity:0.5;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#audioplayer:hover { 
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:37px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
    margin-left:34px;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:1;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#albumart2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
    position:relative;}
 
#albumart2 img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    
}
#albumart {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-105px;
    padding-right:5px;
    position:relative;}
 
#albumart img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    
}

.chat{
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0; 
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
}

.chat.chat1 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.chat .chat1 .chat2 {
    background: # ffffff;
    color:{color:text};
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
    padding: 4px 4px 5px 5px;
    border-style:none;
}

.chat2 {
    background:#D8D8D8;
    color:{color:text};
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
    padding: 4px 4px 5px 5px;
    border-style:none;
}
.chat .chat1 .chat2.even {
    background: #ffffff; 
    color: {color:text};
} 
.chat .chat1 .chat2 span {font-weight: bold;}

#credit {
    margin-top:0px;
    position:fixed;
    width:80px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:3px;
    left:40px
    line-height:5px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font:10px trebuchet ms;
    color: {color:text};
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#credit:hover{
    margin-top:0px;
    position:fixed;
    width:80px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:9px;
    line-height:5px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font:10px trebuchet ms;
    color: {color:text};
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#menuTop{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 225px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    
    
}


#top_description{
    background-color: ;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 265px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
}

#top_description li{
    background-color: ;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    display:block;
}

#top_text{
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
}


{block:ifWebkitScrollbar}

::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 3px; height:5px; background:{color:scrollbg};}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background:{color:scroll};}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {background:{color:scroll}; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {background:{color:scroll};}

{/block:ifWebkitScrollbar}



{CustomCSS}</style></head><body>


<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Petit+Formal+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Seaweed+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a href=""></a><div id="top_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 300px"></a>
    
    

<div id="top_description" style="width: 1200px; height: 35px">
    <div id="menuTop" style="width: 770px; height: 35px">
        <style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
    
}

li {
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    
    
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    text-decoration: ;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", palatino, serif;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color:rgba(126,9,37,0.35);
    height: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    
}

li a:after {
    display:block;
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:4px;
    background:#7e0925;
    margin-top:7px;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li><a href="blah">Who?</a></li>
  <li><a href="blah">Ask</a></li>
  <li><a href="blah">Submit</a></li>
  <li><a href="blah">Original Posts</a></li>
  <li><a href="blah">Disclaimer</a></li>
</ul>
           
    </div>
    
    
</div>


<div id="top_text" style="width: 735px; height: 195px">
    <p>
</>




<div id="panel">
<div id="panelbackground"><img width="400px"<img src="{image:sidebar background}"></div>
<div id="sidebar">


<div class="top"><div id="navigation"><div class="button" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
<a href="blah">who am i?</a>
<a href="blah">ask me</a>
<a href="blah">submit</a>
<a href="blah">my posts</a>
<a href="blah">disclaimer</a>

{block:IfCustomLinkOneTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link One}">{text:Custom Link One Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkOneTitle}

{block:ifCustomLinkTwoTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link Two}">{text:Custom Link Two Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkTwoTitle}

{block:ifCustomLinkThreeTitle}<a href="{text:Custom Link Three}">{text:Custom Link Three Title}</a>{/block:ifCustomLinkThreeTitle}<div id="pagination">
{block:Pagination}
            {block:NextPage}
                <a href="{NextPage}">Next</a>
            {/block:NextPage}
            {block:PreviousPage}
                <a href="{PreviousPage}">Prev</a>
            {/block:PreviousPage}
        {/block:Pagination}
</div>
</div></div></div>



<div id="title">{Title}</div><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anaheim' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<div id="sidebarimage"><img width="200px"height="200px""<img src="{image:sidebar image}"></div>


<div id="description">{description}</div>





</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="credit"><a target="blank"href="http://accioloki.tumblr.com"><font color="{color:text}">© accioloki </a></font></div>

<div id="entries">{block:Posts}

<div id="post">



<div class="info">posted {TimeAgo} {block:RebloggedFrom} | <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="via"> via </a> | {block:ContentSource}<a href="{SourceURL}" title="©"> © </a>{/block:ContentSource}{/block:RebloggedFrom} | <a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount}</a>{block:HasTags}{block:Tags} #<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}</div>


{block:Text}<h1>{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}</h1>{Body}{/block:Text} 

{block:Photo}{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}">{LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photo} 

{block:Photoset}{Photoset-500}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}<div id="quote">“</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{Quote}<br>
{block:Source}<div align="right">— {Source}</div>{/block:Source}
    {/block:Quote} 

{block:Link}<h1><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></h1>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:Link} 

<div class="chat">
<div class="chat1">
{Block:Lines}
<div class="chat2 {Alt}">
{Block:Label}
<span>{Label}</span>
{/block:Label} 
{Line}</div>
{/block:Lines}
    
</div>
</div>



{block:Audio}
<div id= "audioplayer">{AudioPlayerGrey}</div>
<div id="albumart2"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/4wyqgof/Dyvm2qmp1/default.jpg"></div>{block:AlbumArt}<div id="albumart"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}"></div>{/block:AlbumArt}
<br>{block:Artist}
{Artist}
{/block:Artist}
{block:TrackName}
{TrackName}
{/block:TrackName}
{block:Album}
{Album}
{/block:Album}
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Audio} 

{block:Video}{Video-500}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Video} 

{block:Answer}<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}" align="left" class="askborder"><div class="bubble"><span></span>{Asker}: {Question}&nbsp;</div>{Answer}{/block:Answer}


</div>




{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:Posts}</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: post all of your code here

Comment: Okay, I posted the whole code now

Answer (score 1):

Look up "overflow:hidden;" on google. That removes the scrollbar

Comment: The issue is not the scrollbar, I want the scrollbar to appear. I just don't want the scrolling of the page to "carry" the side menu on top of the rest of the page content to its right.

Comment: It sounds like you need to "float" the menu to the left? and the "entries" is "z-indexed" to 1, meaning it will be on-top of the menu

Comment: The panel and the panel:hover divs are floating left already. And I tried changing the z index but it didn't help

Comment: I managed to get the panel to stay left by changing it to position:relative. The problem now is that the divs inside panel still move out of it and to the right when side-scrolling. I did add the float:left to both panel, hover and entries.

Comment: Dont touch position. It will mess everything up, logically! :) im on my laptop therefore no dreamveawer, so hopefully someonbe else can answer, But ill take another look..

Comment: Do you want - panel and sidebar next to eachother?

Comment: No, I think the panel is inside sidebar. The #panel is already staying in the right place. The problem now is what is inside #panel. At this point all I need is to force #navigation, #description, #sidebarimage and #title to remain horizontally still when scrolling sideways. I think those divs are all inside #panel. Maybe .top is also related, I'm not sure.

Comment: UPDATE: Seems like if I can just fix the #sidebarimage div in place, it will all be fine. It is scrolling downwards and sidewards and carrying everything with it. Either that or #sidebar

Comment: UPDATE 2: I only need to get the #navigation or #top div to not go up when hovering.